# JS Regex for matching specific array increment ignoring string and seperate increment

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, regex, preg-match

I have the following input fields with name attributes of:

```
carousels['components'][0][0][title]
carousels['components'][0][1][title]
carousels['components'][0][2][title]

carousels['components'][1][0][title]
carousels['components'][1][1][title]
carousels['components'][1][2][title]

carousels['components'][2][0][title]
carousels['components'][2][1][title]
carousels['components'][2][2][title]
```

I am trying to match the final [ number ] eg this part:

```
carousels['components'][2][THIS][title]
carousels['components'][2][THIS][title]
carousels['components'][2][THIS][title]
```

While ignoring the rest

Here is my regex pattern:

```
/(\[[^components\]])+(\[*])/
```

This affects both of the int's within brackets when I just want the last one. This regex also doesn't recognize the specific requirement of the first array key 'component'

Live regex test here:

http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to get the *last* `[` + `digits` + `]`**, you can use

```
/^.*\[(\d+)\].*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC1hA6/1)

Backtracking will help getting exactly the last occurrence of `[digits]`. Grab  Group 1 value.

```js
var re = /^.*\[(\d+)\].*$/; 
var str = 'carousels[\'components\'][0][0][title]\ncarousels[\'components\'][0][1][title]\ncarousels[\'components\'][0][2][title]\n\ncarousels[\'components\'][1][0][title]\ncarousels[\'components\'][1][1][title]\ncarousels[\'components\'][1][2][title]\n\ncarousels[\'components\'][2][0][title]\ncarousels[\'components\'][2][1][title]\ncarousels[\'components\'][2][2][title]';

for (var s of str.split("\n")) {
    var res = (m=re.exec(s)) ? m[1] : "";
    if (res) {
      document.body.innerHTML += s + ": " + res + "<br/>";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

**To get the *first* `[` + `digits` + `]`**, you need to use lazy matching with the first dot:

```
/^.*?\[(\d+)\].*$/
    ^ - Here, the ? will make matching lazy/reluctant 
        (it will match any 0+ chars other than a newline as few as possible)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC1hA6/2).

Comment: Thanks this is perfect, although I just realised I need to retrieve the first [digits] rather than the second lot. Just fiddling around with the regex

Comment: Then use `.*?` at the beginning. I added this regex with a bit of explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your help - greedy isn't going to work in this instance (using replace method) - can I start the string search from ['components']?

Comment: You have only mentioned you need to *match* something. Now, you say you need to *replace*. Ok, what is the sample output for e.g. `carousels['components'][0][0][title]`?

Comment: Sorry - link here: https://regex101.com/r/yC1hA6/4 - exact requirement is to replace ['components'][1][0], 'components'][1][1], 'components'][1][2] etc with ['components'][2][0], 'components'][2][1], 'components'][2][2]

Comment: Your input is not that clear to me, if it is multiline, you can try `.replace(/^(.*?\['components'\]\[)\d+\]/gm, '$12]')`. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u40gsqhq/).

Comment: Perfect - it was my replace that was incorrect. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
    ^.*(\[.*?\])\[.*?\]$
       <------->
Match in this(1st captured group)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR9hX2/2)**

If you want to match `['components']` exclusively, then you can use

```
^.*\['components'\].*(\[.*?\])\[.*?\]$
```